# Поиск по своим меткам

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-places-api

В конструкторе карт создал около 200-т меток. Как осуществлять поиск среди созданный меток?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, пока поиска по Моим картам нет.